# Why is Mono implementing WCF?

Tags: wcf, mono, monodevelop

Why is the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) [implementing WCF](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development) interfaces and classes "as is"?

I do not understand what is the point to repeat Microsoft's design. My experience says that WCF is a huge framework with an implementation based on SOAP services. There are tremendous problems with their approach. It simply does not fit well for simple HTTP request processing cycle. Why not try to invent a better framework instead?

Update:

OK, I get it. :) I like the .NET platform, C# and I like that this platform is available on another OS, but ...

Don't you guys see that many things in the original (Microsoft) frameworks can be done better?
Look at `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message`. This is one of big things of customization landscape.

Why do I see XML everywhere? How can I easily do anything with classes like this? It is feasible, but I cannot say this is good design for a general purpose communication framework. I thought that the purpose of the Mono project is not just bringing the .NET ecosystem to unix* but make it better.

Comment: WCF isn't based on soap services, it allows bindings to soap services, but you can also expose restful services using wcf, with only a little configuration.

Comment: did you ever try add compression for json, xml services? it is not easy at all.

Comment: They wouldn't be able to say they were implementing "WCF" on mono if they didn't, you know, **implement WCF**. If you don't like WCF, you don't have to use it.

Comment: You could ask exactly the same thing about why Mono implemented C# in the first place.

Comment: I'm implementing WCF right now as an interprocess data communications mechanism.  Strongly typed, easy to use, and call backs - I'm loving it!

Comment: WCF is beautiful. As a person who wishes it existed on my non-.net language/platform of choice, I wish I had WCF.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the whole point is to make **WCF platform** available in other operating systems than **Microsoft Windows**. So, if you have an application developed with **MS VisualStudio** (Microsoft's compilers), you can deploy it on Linux or Mac OS X if you wish.

You can also use **MonoDevelop** and **Mono Compilers** if you decide to code **WCF** in alternative platforms.

Answer (score 8):

Because not everything is suitable for a simple http request processing cycle. Because SOAP offers features REST does not. Because it hooks into a wide set of encryption, authentication and authorization options. Because what you see as as tremendous problems solve problems for others.

Comment: "Because what you see as as tremendous problems solve problems for others." - Great soundbyte - I know I'm going to use that sentence in a different debate.

Answer (score 6):

Mono exists to allow .net on other OS's. Mono is not about picking and choosing what to implement based on merit.